# android mediaplayer start called in state error

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-button, ontouchlistener

```
final MediaPlayer buttononclick = MediaPlayer.create(this, soundtrack);
            ImageButton tempbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(i);
            tempbutton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            try {
                                if (buttononclick != null) {
                                    buttononclick.start();
                                }
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            buttononclick.stop();
                            return true;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

I have been working on buttons which can make sound when i click the button and stop the sound when i release the button. if i click the button again the sound will start from the beginning like the piano. but the error shows :state 64 and start called in state 0 error.

```
01-31 13:32:01.526  13888-13888/com.cambo.liyuan.projectcombo E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 64
01-31 13:32:01.526  13888-13888/com.cambo.liyuan.projectcombo E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
01-31 13:32:01.526  13888-13888/com.cambo.liyuan.projectcombo E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)
01-31 13:32:01.892  13888-13888/com.cambo.liyuan.projectcombo E/MediaPlayer﹕ stop called in state 0
01-31 13:32:01.892  13888-13888/com.cambo.liyuan.projectcombo E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)
```

01-31 13:32:01.892  13888-13888/com.cambo.liyuan.projectcombo E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (-38,0)

i have been looking at the state diagram of mediaplayer and tried several ways posted on stackflow to make it work, but it keep through the error or illegalstatementexception if i checked isPlaying() before it st or set prepare() before start ect...
Someone said assign the player to null after stop it but it is a final variable.
I will be gratefully appraciated if can help me figure out the correct way of implementing this function.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this after `buttononclick.stop();`

`buttononclick.reset();`
`buttononclick.release();`

and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment  but there is         `java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaPlayer._stop(Native Method)` when edit in reset() and release()

Comment: I found that it crashed when i click any button more than once. if i click each of them for once only, it works perfectly.